# select item and sum of items with same table

Tags: sql, sum

i have table item like

```
  id  |  name | amount
 -----+-------------
    1 | item1 | 3
    2 | item2 | 6
    3 | item2 | 7
    4 | item2 | 6
    5 | item3 | 3
    6 | item3 | 2
```

how i can get all with sum of items like

```
  n   |  name | sum
 -----+-------------
    1 | item1 | 3
    2 | item2 | 19
    3 | item3 | 5
```

i have try this but it doesnt works

```
SELECT a.name FROM item a
JOIN
( SELECT SUM( amount ), name
  FROM item group by id
) AS b
ON b.name= a.name
```

Comment: What does column n represent?

Comment: And if it is what we thing it is (i.e. what follows `item` in the name), why do you need it/why isn't it in your `item` table ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You request is strange for what you want to do... You should just do :

```
SELECT I.name, SUM(I.amount) 
FROM item I
WHERE 1
GROUP BY I.name
ORDER BY I.name ASC ;
```

If you want to have `n`:

```
SET @num=0;
SELECT @num:=@num+1 AS n, I.name AS name, SUM(I.amount) AS sum
FROM item I
WHERE 1
GROUP BY I.name
ORDER BY I.name ASC ;
```

If you want to order `name` AND `n`, you have to do 2 selects :

```
SET @num=0;
SELECT @num:=@num+1 AS n, I.name AS name, I.sum AS sum
FROM (SELECT I.name AS name, SUM(I.amount) AS sum
      FROM item I
      WHERE 1
      GROUP BY I.name
      ORDER BY I.name ASC) AS I
WHERE 1 ;
```

Comment: How does this query get the `id` column?

Comment: @RagingBull I've updated my answer, but `n` certainly didn't come from the `id` column, because if it did, it would be `1`, `2`, `5`.

Comment: Removed my downvote. +1 you deserve it too. And deleted my answer.